# DevExtreme - MyApp.app.navigation[x].option("badge", "x") not working

Tags: javascript, devextreme, phonejs

I'm trying to create a badge on a slide out navigation item, but I can't seem to make it work.

Basically I have a *Login* that can create *Hour Registrations*. These registrations needs to be either confirmed or denied by a *Login* with *Role_ID* = 1.

After a *Login* has logged in (if *Role_ID* = 1), I pull out all of these *Hour Registrations* from my service, and then does this:

```
if (data.Role.Id === 1) {
                   HourRegistrationApplication.config.navigation[7].visible(true);

                   $.getJSON(baseAddress + "hours/head/" + data.Id,
                       function (hourRegArray) {
                           if (hourRegArray.length != 0) {
                               console.log(hourRegArray.length);
                               HourRegistrationApplication.app.navigation[7].option("badge", hourRegArray.length);
                           }
                       });

               }
```

Where `hourRegArray` is the JSON that I return:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Hours": 5,
    "Date": "27/08/2015",
    "Comment": "Stackoverflow rocks",
    "Login_ID": 1
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Hours": 3,
    "Date": "25/08/2015",
    "Comment": "Stackoverflow rocks even more!",
    "Login_ID": 1
  }
]
```

Then I wish to have the value of `badge` to be the `hourRegArray.length`, but for some strange reason I get this error:

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected

What exactly is causing the problem here?

I've made a support ticket on the DevExtreme support forum, and the support told me to update my project to the latest 15.1.6 (I think it is now), didn't make any difference, I get the same error.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: @Sergey Sorry I didn't update on my progress. Yes I solved the problem. I sent my project to the DevExtreme support, and they updated my project for me (Don't know why my update didn't work), which fixed the problem. Apparently this was a bug in the version I was using prior to the update.

Comment: Thank you for clarification!